# how to print barcode with high quality

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, barcode-printing

I am creating an image of a ticket with System.Drawing.Graphics in WinForm C#.
The image contains a text which I generate with Graphics.DrawString, A logo that I load with Graphics.DrawImage, And a barcode that I manually draw with Graphics.DrawLine.

The generated image looks great digitally but the problem is that at the moment of printing the image looks great except the barcode, that is printed with poor quality, I had already tried  many libraries to generate bar codes, but the bar code continues to print with  poor quality, so I choose to draw it manually, but regardless of my effort, it still looks with low resolution.

If someone knows any configuration to generated and printed my barcode with high resolution I would appreciate it very much for your help

Comment: What is the format of the output picture? Don't want to assume anything but maybe you are using a vector image instead of something like bitmap?

Comment: Barcode is a font. You should do it with `DrawString` and correct font.

Comment: @JoãoMiguelBrandão, the  fromat of output picture is jpg and the resolution is 300 dpi. this is my code Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(606, 1669);
                bm.SetResolution(300, 300);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);

Comment: The suggestion to use the Barcode font is a good one. Of course, it means you have to have that font installed. If you want to draw the barcode yourself, you need to match the printer resolution. See marked duplicates for options to do that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, Already try to do it with drawString and a barcode font, but it comes out with very poor resolution this is my code `Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(606, 1669);
                bm.SetResolution(300, 300);
                Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.DrawString("321456258", new Font("Code 39", 18f, GraphicsUnit.Inch),new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(10,10));`